# Spark Error reading csv file

Tags: csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read a local csv file with Spark (version 2.2.1 / windows 10) with following code :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
val df =  

 spark.read
 .option("header","true")
 .option("inferSchema","true")
 .csv("CitiGroup")

 df.printSchema()
```

But i have an error saying **'df not found'** and in the derby file i found a long error print starts like this :

```
> Fri Jun 22 17:43:27 CEST 2018 Thread[main,5,main] Cleanup action starting
java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'metastore_db' with class loader org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1@2c6d5b2e, see the next exception for details.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.seeNextException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.bootDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.obtainRawInternalConnection(BoneCP.java:349)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.<init>(BoneCP.java:416)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource.getConnection(BoneCPDataSource.java:120)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl.getConnection(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:501)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.<init>(RDBMSStoreManager.java:298)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:631)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:301)
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.createStoreManagerForProperties(NucleusContext.java:1187)
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.initialise(NucleusContext.java:356)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:775)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:333)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:202)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:701)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:365)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:394)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:291)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:258)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:593)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:571)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:620)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:461)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5762)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:86)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3005)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3024)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllDatabases(Hive.java:1234)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<clinit>(Hive.java:166)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:503)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:191)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:266)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client$lzycompute(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply$mcZ$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.externalCatalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog$lzycompute(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder.build(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$instantiateSessionState(SparkSession.scala:1059)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sessionState$2.apply(SparkSession.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sessionState$2.apply(SparkSession.scala:136)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.<init>(DataFrameReader.scala:689)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.read(SparkSession.scala:645)
    at $line35.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:30)
    at $line35.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:35)
    at $line35.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:37)
    at $line35.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:39)
    at $line35.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:41)
    at $line35.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:43)
    at $line35.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:45)
    at $line35.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:47)
    at $line35.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:49)
    at $line35.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:51)
    at $line35.$read.<init>(<console>:53)
    at $line35.$read$.<init>(<console>:57)
    at $line35.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at $line35.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
    at $line35.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
    at $line35.$eval.$print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:786)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1047)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:638)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:637)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:637)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:569)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:565)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:807)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:681)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:395)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:415)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$interpretAllFrom$1$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(ILoop.scala:427)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$interpretAllFrom$1$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(ILoop.scala:423)
    at scala.reflect.io.Streamable$Chars$class.applyReader(Streamable.scala:111)
    at scala.reflect.io.File.applyReader(File.scala:50)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$interpretAllFrom$1$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(ILoop.scala:423)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$interpretAllFrom$1$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(ILoop.scala:423)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.savingReplayStack(ILoop.scala:91)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$interpretAllFrom$1.apply(ILoop.scala:422)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$interpretAllFrom$1.apply(ILoop.scala:422)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.savingReader(ILoop.scala:96)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretAllFrom(ILoop.scala:421)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$run$3$1.apply(ILoop.scala:577)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$run$3$1.apply(ILoop.scala:576)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.withFile(ILoop.scala:570)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.run$3(ILoop.scala:576)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loadCommand(ILoop.scala:583)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$standardCommands$8.apply(ILoop.scala:207)

    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMAccessManager$5.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMAccessManager.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMAccessManager.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase$5.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.bootStore(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.bootService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startProviderService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.findProviderAndStartService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
    ... 171 more
============= begin nested exception, level (1) ===========
java.sql.SQLException: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database D:\Spark-Scala\Projet-test\metastore_db.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.bootDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.obtainRawInternalConnection(BoneCP.java:349)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.<init>(BoneCP.java:416)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource.getConnection(BoneCPDataSource.java:120)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl.getConnection(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:501)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.<init>(RDBMSStoreManager.java:298)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:631)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:301)
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.createStoreManagerForProperties(NucleusContext.java:1187)
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.initialise(NucleusContext.java:356)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:775)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:333)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:202)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:701)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:365)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:394)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:291)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:258)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:593)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:571)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:620)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:461)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:72)

    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.bootDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.obtainRawInternalConnection(BoneCP.java:349)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.<init>(BoneCP.java:416)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource.getConnection(BoneCPDataSource.java:120)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl.getConnection(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:501)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.<init>(RDBMSStoreManager.java:298)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder.build(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$instantiateSessionState(SparkSession.scala:1059)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sessionState$2.apply(SparkSession.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sessionState$2.apply(SparkSession.scala:136)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.<init>(DataFrameReader.scala:689)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.read(SparkSession.scala:645)
    at $line35.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:30)
    at $line35.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:35)
    at $line35.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:37)
    at $line35.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:39)
    at $line35.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:41)
    at $line35.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:43)
    at $line35.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:45)
    at $line35.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:47)
    at $line35.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:49)
    at $line35.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:51)
    at $line35.$read.<init>(<console>:53)
    at $line35.$read$.<init>(<console>:57)
    at $line35.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at $line35.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
    at $line35.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
    at $line35.$eval.$print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:786)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1047)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:638)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:637)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:637)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:569)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:565)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:807)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:681)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:395)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:415)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$interpretAllFrom$1$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(ILoop.scala:427)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$interpretAllFrom$1$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(ILoop.scala:423)
    at scala.reflect.io.Streamable$Chars$class.applyReader(Streamable.scala:111)
    at scala.reflect.io.File.applyReader(File.scala:50)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$interpretAllFrom$1$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(ILoop.scala:423)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$interpretAllFrom$1$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(ILoop.scala:423)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.savingReplayStack(ILoop.scala:91)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$interpretAllFrom$1.apply(ILoop.scala:422)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$interpretAllFrom$1.apply(ILoop.scala:422)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.savingReader(ILoop.scala:96)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretAllFrom(ILoop.scala:421)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$run$3$1.apply(ILoop.scala:577)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$run$3$1.apply(ILoop.scala:576)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.withFile(ILoop.scala:570)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.run$3(ILoop.scala:576)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loadCommand(ILoop.scala:583)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$standardCommands$8.apply(ILoop.scala:207)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$standardCommands$8.apply(ILoop.scala:207)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.LoopCommands$LineCmd.apply(LoopCommands.scala:62)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.colonCommand(ILoop.scala:688)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:679)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:395)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:415)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:923)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:909)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
============= end nested exception, level (2) ===========
Cleanup action completed
```

Comment: please post all  the log error

Comment: It's a very long log file, i put a piece of it since i can't paste it all in here .

Comment: Have you checked that you don't have already a spark application started from the same folder? `java.sql.SQLException: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database D:\Spark-Scala\Projet-test\metastore_db.
` sounds like there was a resource collision

Comment: Yes i am pretty sure that is the only app running , i have even closed Ms Excel ( nothing to do i know but who knows .. )

Answer (score 0):

you have missed the option below while creating spark session

.master(“local[*]”).appName(“test”)

add this and try

Comment: I have tryied it but nothing has really changed, in fact, when i get in spark-shell it shows this : "Spark session available as 'spark'."

Comment: Restart spark machine

Answer (score 0):

**Issue :**

> java.sql.SQLException: Another instance of Derby may have already
>   booted the database D:\Spark-Scala\Projet-test\metastore_db.

This issue happens because of Metastore_db.
Metastore_db created everytime when the spark shell is looking for db and start registering it.

First check you should have read write permission

Then Remove "Metastore_db"

If you are not able to delete then first delete metastore_db/dbex.lck
then after you can delete the metastore_db folder

**Now come to your code :**

Though code is not creating issue here however sharing sample here

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import sparkSession.implicits._


val sparkContext = sparkSession.sparkContext


SparkSession spark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .appName("VaquarKhan-Example")
            .master("local[4]") 
            .getOrCreate();


 val df = sparkSession.read
   .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
   .option("header","true")
   .schema(customSchema)
   .option("inferSchema","true")
   .csv("CitiGroup")

    df.printSchema()
```

Comment: error: not found: value sparkSession
       import sparkSession.implicits._
              ^
<console>:32: error: value sparkContext is not a member of object org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
       val sparkContext = SparkSession.sparkContext